# Why doesn't the common ForkJoinPool try to use all cores?

Tags: java, threadpool, fork-join

I understand why thread pool sizes are tied to the number of CPU cores, but why did the designers of `ForkJoinThread` default to using `# of cpu cores - 1` threads? Why the `-1`?

If I am constructing my own `ForkJoinPool` (not using the common instance), and the `main` thread is blocked on the pool waiting for it to return some result, is there any reason I would want to allocate less than `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` threads?

**UPDATE**: Please explain why you are down-voting. Otherwise, I can't improve the question.

Comment: The JVM will typically reserve some number of cores to do Garbage Collection. It is highly dependant on the architecture that you're running on, and which GC implementation has been chosen. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/toc.html

Comment: @AndrewRueckert Instead of downvoting with a comment, why not post this as an answer? It is a reasonable explanation.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I didn't think my answer was solid enough to qualify as "Answer". Turns out I was wrong, anyways! :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a comment in the [Oracle JDK implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.java?av=f#627). It states

```
 * When external threads submit to the common pool, they can
 * perform subtask processing (see externalHelpComplete and
 * related methods) upon joins.  This caller-helps policy makes it
 * sensible to set common pool parallelism level to one (or more)
 * less than the total number of available cores, or even zero for
 * pure caller-runs.
```

In other words, when external (not part of the FJP's threads) (can) help with the execution of tasks, additional threads aren't always beneficial.

Comment: Good find. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This makes sense. One thread is always required for the main thread and the max number of threads running at once is the total number of cores. Hence, the default parallelism being `# of cpu cores - 1`.